# M.2 WD Blue 1TB SSD locked with ATA password - how to unlock via Linux?

Tags: ssd, passwd

Well, I have an M.2 SSD with 1TB of capacity, that was locked by the user in his Fujitsu U Series laptop. Then the motherboard died and was replaced. Both the passwords master/user are unknown. The goal now is to unlock the SSD and reuse it. Data is not important and can be wiped. And just to let you know, I'm not a linux-man, I'm only self educated and I am learning along the way... I first tried the bootable DOS flash with with UltimateBOOT CD 5.3.8 together with the ZU.exe tool, but that didn't work for me so I moved forward to Linux.

Using

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb
```

I get (security part only)

```
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
        enabled
        locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    Security level high
    2min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 2min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5001b444a664843e
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 001b44
    Unique ID   : 4a664843e
Device Sleep:
    DEVSLP Exit Timeout (DETO): 30 ms (drive)
    Minimum DEVSLP Assertion Time (MDAT): 30 ms (drive)
Checksum: correct
```

What shall I do next? What is the correct procedure to get rid of the lock, please?

Thank you!